# MFC: Is it possible to modify the dialog style at run time? Pin

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I have createed a dialog template resource, in the dialog editor I set the WS_POPUP property.

It's fine to generate the modal dialog with the template resource.

Here is my problem: I want to change it's style from WS_POPUP to WS_CHILD since I want to generate the dialog in the property page(CPropertySheet).

I have tried many ways. Change the dialog in OnInitDialog,OnCreate,PreCreateWindow,PreSubclassWindow with ModifyStyle or SetWindowLong 
doesn't work.

Now I wonder whether it's possible to generate the dialog with the same resource and modify the style.

Besides, the method list in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13133/Modifying-a-modal-dialog-s-style-and-position-at-r doesn't work either.

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to use the same dialog template for a property page and a standalone dialog?

Comment: Yes. But I can't achive that.

Comment: You need to copy the template and then edit the style in the copy.

Comment: In `OnInitDialog()`, you may need to remove some styles, as well as adding your desired one. I found a helpful discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/d74451eb-fc45-4260-8ce1-2fdcf326c5e8

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the dialog template to WS_CHILD, it can be used as both a child and as a popup dialog.